# When do we first hear the name "Anakin"?

Tags: star-wars, names, anakin-skywalker

I recently watched the Original Star Wars Trilogy and I don't remember the name "Anakin" being said that much.

However Wookieepedia states:

> Annikin Starkiller was the proposed name for the lead character in the what would become Episode IV and appeared in the rough draft. (...) He became the source of Luke's father's name, Anakin
>
> <sub>[Annikin Starkiller - Behind the scenes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Annikin_Starkiller#Behind_the_scenes)</sub>

If the above is true and the name really originated back in early drafts of Ep. IV then I am surprised if we really don't *hear* the name a lot more often. **When do we first hear the name "Anakin" in the Original *Unaltered* Trilogy?**

Comment: I think that in the DVD edition, the emperor tells Vader "I believe he's the son of Anakin Skywalker" in episode V. I don't know if that was recorded for ep V in the beginning but removed or dubbed later.

Comment: @GeorgeT Added later; I had the same thought but was swiftly corrected. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases#Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_3

Comment: @George T - In the original theatrical version of that scene he just says "son of Skywalker", you can see it on youtube at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKtciRCVpFE

Comment: @Hypnosifl: You misunderstood me; I'm aware this was added in the DVD edition. What I don't know is if it's a part that had been removed before the film originally aired, or created from nothing.

Comment: @GeorgeT Lucas changed the scene later, now using Ian McDiarmid to play the Emperor. The visuals of the Emperor were completely reshot with the new actor, with new dialogue recorded and everything. Most of Vader's lines are unaltered, but he now says "how is that possible?" where before he didn't. Originally it was just "son of Skywalker", now it's "offspring of Anakin Skywalker".

Comment: @Nathan K. Campbell -- According to [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases) and [this article](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-wars-changes/), McDiarmid wasn't added to the 1997 Special Edition of ESB, he first appeared in ESB on the 2004 DVD edition.

Comment: I stand corrected and will modify my comment! Thanks! I'd have to go pull out the VHS to confirm and nobody wants that!

Comment: @GeorgeT - the original script says "son of Skywalker" pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/… - page 102 of the PDF The scene was originally shot as a visual effect and did not include Ian McDiarmid (as he was cast for RoTJ). McDiarmid was added later and reshot for the 2004 DVD release.

Comment: I remember watching them as they were released, and we had no idea what his name was until Jedi. I mean we were still reeling from the fact that he was Luke's father which was like the biggest reveal of the entire 1980's except maybe who shot J.R., so we didn't really care what his first name was at the time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first in-canon mention of Vader's true name (within the original ***unimproved*** trilogy) is in RotJ, during the scene where Luke speaks with the Force-ghost of Kenobi.

> **LUKE:** *You told me Vader betrayed and murdered my father.*
>
> **BEN:** *You father was seduced by the dark side of
>                  the Force. **He ceased to be Anakin Skywalker
>                  and became Darth Vader.** When that happened,
>                  the good man who was your father was
>                  destroyed. So what I have told you was
>                  true... from a certain point of view.*

That being said, there's absolutely no indication that Luke doesn't already know this name and it would be very odd if he hadn't known it from childhood.

---

You may be fooled into thinking that there was an earlier reference in ESB...

> **Emperor:** *We have a new enemy. The young Rebel who destroyed the Death Star. I have no doubt **this boy is the offspring of Anakin
>   Skywalker***

... however this was retconned into the Special Edition (the [original wording](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKtciRCVpFE) was "*...son of Skywalker*")

---

For completeness, I should mention that the name itself appears in one of the very earliest [draft scripts](http://whills.nu/4/sw2.html) for the movie "The Star Wars", written some **4 years** before A New Hope was ever filmed, so clearly Lucas always knew what Vader's real name was, even if the rest of us didn't:

> *"A harsh gale blows across the bleak grey surface of the Fourth Moon.  The leaden sky presses down on a lone figure, ANNIKIN STARKILLER"*

Comment: Isn't Annikin Luke's previous name, though? The character, not the General in the original script

Comment: @Francisco - The characters changed so dramatically between the early drafts, it's not really clear which character became Luke. Note also that Luke was Leia (a female character) at one point in the story.

Answer (score 13):

One could argue that Ben Kenobi, in his hut in Episode 4 says "Ani was a good friend"

In the 'real world' - Sir Alec was likely saying "and he was a good friend" - but, since we have precedent for Anakin being nicknamed "Ani" as early as Episode 1, the ambiguous diction, as well as 'correct' viewing order may lead future viewers to clearly hear Ben Kenobi say "Ani"

Comment: Clever, but the script makes it clear that it was "and he was my good friend".

Comment: After the death of his mother, Anakin becomes Little Orphan Annie. :-)